# get or pass values from jsp to spring mvc controller with @RequestParam("VIEW") annotation

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

Hi everyone I'm trying to get or pass the values from my JSP to my controller because I want to write a method whose main function will be to save a new user in the database but I got an error like this:

```
(((java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mode mappings conflict between method and type level: [/myPath] versus [VIEW])))
```

I guess this two annotations, first in the class declaration @RequestMapping("VIEW") and the second in the method declaration for save the new user

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/saveUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

are in conflict by the use of the same annotation in tow times at the same controller but I have to say that I´ve been tried to remove the @RequestMapping annotation in the class declaration and after that, I get a different error like this:

```
(((java.lang.IllegalStateException: No portlet mode mappings specified - neither at type nor at method level)))
```

I don't know if I can use as many necessary controllers for differents operations as I will need, if I can, I will be happy to know the correct way to implement with this technique

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("VIEW")
public class UsersController {

  User currentUser = null;

  @RenderMapping
  public ModelAndView view(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response)throws Exception {

    ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView();
    UserDTO usuarioAdd = new UserDTO();

    //blah, blah, blah...

    return modelView;
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/saveUser", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public void saveUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
      logger.info("***SAVE USER***);
      System.out.println("***SAVE USER***);
  }

}
```

Comment: can you share your code of controller

Comment: of course and thanks in advance.